# pass date as commit message in git

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

Git offers a command to post commit message when commiting files:

Looks like this:

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

I would like to replace commit message with current date and time.
The function to call is just `date`, but git doesn't know that date should be equal to current date and time. How can I send current date and time as a commit message?

Comment: As you might know, the git history already contains the date/time of a commit. Do you mind to elaborate why you'd want this in the message?

Comment: Either way: Did you try the (unix) "date" command?

Comment: It just says 3h ago or something like that. Not really useful. Although I don't  know what will it say later I am only using it for 3h :D yes I used date, I report about it's failure in original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use: `git -m "$(date)"`

It will use 'date' tool, but imho stupid idea, git logs date anyway, message commit is for different purposes. Check result of `git log` command

Comment: Thank you. I didnt use $ character. It just says 3h ago or something like that.  Although I don't know what will it say later I am only using it for 3h

Comment: @sanjihan On my repo it shows for example: Date:   Fri Apr 22 10:03:26 2016 +0200 , i think that it depends on some kind of flag or default setting, how it's formatted. Anyway git stores full date of commit, not relative one.

Comment: Than I agree. Stupid idea indeed.

Comment: Is it just me or is it not stupid if you want to make commits programmatically? It seems like the easiest way to do that to me, but if someone has an easier way let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could put these lines in your `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "1 s/^/$(date)/" "$1"
```

That will automatically prepend the current date to all your commit messages.